# Intuitive explanation of unit root

Tags: intuition, unit-root

How would you explain intuitively what is a unit root, in the context of the unit root test?

I'm thinking in ways of explaining much like I've founded in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17537/understanding-variance-intuitively).

The case with unit root is that I know (little, by the way) that the unit root test is used to test for stationarity in a time series, but it's just it.

How would you go to explain it to the layperson, or to a person who has studied a very basic probability and statistics course?

**UPDATE**

I accepted whuber's answer as it is what most reflect what I asked here. But I urge everybody that came here to read Patrick's and Michael's answers also, as they are the natural "next step" in understanding the Unit Root. They use mathematics, but in a very intuitive way.

Comment: I have upvoted all three current answers to this question (Michael Chernick's, Patrick Caldon's, & whuber's). Taken together, I believe they provide a thorough understanding of the unit root, from the intuition to some of the underlying mathematics. +1 for a productive question.

Comment: Yeah, @gung, I'm really surprised by the quality of the answers. Now it's my number 1 link when anyone asks me about Unit Root.

Comment: I can't compete with Pooh, but [here's another graphical take.][1] The last two series (R and E) don't have a unit root and are not stationary. You can see that how far they drift around.


  [1]: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25481/7071.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

> He  had  just come to the bridge; and not looking where he was going,
> he  tripped  over  something,  and  the  fir-cone jerked out of his
> paw into the river.
>
> "Bother,"  said  Pooh,  as  it floated slowly under the bridge, and he went back to get another fir-cone  which  had  a rhyme
> to it. But then he thought that he would just look at the river
> instead, because it was a peaceful sort of day, so he lay down and
> looked at it, and it slipped slowly away beneath him . . . and
> suddenly, there was his fir-cone slipping away too.
>
> "That's  funny,"  said Pooh. "I dropped it on the other side," said Pooh, "and it came out on this side! I wonder if it would do it again?"

A.A. Milne, [The House at Pooh Corner](http://www.lib.ru/MILN/pooh2.txt) (Chapter VI.  In which Pooh invents a new game and eeyore joins in.)

Here is a picture of the flow along the surface of the water:

[image: Pooh sticks 1]

The arrows show the direction of flow and are connected by *streamlines.*  A fir cone will tend to follow the streamline in which it falls.  But it doesn't always do it the same way each time, even when it's dropped in the same place in the stream: *random variations* along its path, caused by turbulence in the water, wind, and other whims of nature kick it onto neighboring stream lines.

[image: Pooh sticks 2]

Here, the fir cone was dropped near the upper right corner.  It more or less followed the stream lines--which converge and flow away down and to the left--but it took little detours along the way.

---

An "autoregressive process" (AR process) is a sequence of numbers thought to behave like certain flows.  The two-dimensional illustration corresponds to a process in which each number is determined by its *two* preceding values--plus a random "detour."  The analogy is made by interpreting each successive pair in the sequence as coordinates of a point in the stream.  Instant by instant, the stream's flow changes the fir cone's coordinates in the same mathematical way given by the AR process.

We can recover the original process from the flow-based picture by writing the coordinates of each point occupied by the fir cone and then erasing all but the last number in each set of coordinates.

Nature--and streams in particular--is richer and more varied than the flows corresponding to AR processes.  Because each number in the sequence is assumed to depend *in the same fixed way* on its predecessors--apart from the random detour part--the flows that illustrate AR processes exhibit limited patterns.  They can indeed seem to flow like a stream, as seen here.  They can also look like the swirling around a drain.  The flows can occur in reverse, seeming to gush outwards from a drain.  And they can look like mouths of two streams crashing together: two sources of water flow directly at one another and then split away to the sides.  But that's about it.  You can't have, say, a flowing stream with eddies off to the sides.  AR processes are too simple for that.

[image: Pooh sticks 3]

In this flow, the fir cone was dropped at the lower right corner and quickly carried into the eddy in the upper right, despite the slight random changes in position it underwent.  But it will never quite stop moving, due to those same random movements which rescue it from oblivion.  The fir cone's coordinates move around a bit--indeed, they are seen to oscillate, on the whole, around the coordinates of the center of the eddy.  In the first stream flow, the coordinates progressed inevitably along the center of the stream, which quickly captured the cone and carried it away faster than its random detours could slow it down: they *trend in time.*  By contrast, circling around an eddy exemplifies a *stationary* process in which the fir cone is captured; flowing away down the stream, in which the cone flows out of sight--trending--is non-stationary.

Incidentally, when the flow for an AR process moves away downstream, it also *accelerates.*  It gets faster and faster as the cone moves along it.

The nature of an AR flow is determined by a few special, "characteristic," directions, which are usually evident in the stream diagram: streamlines seem to converge towards or come from these directions.  One can always find as many characteristic directions as there are coefficients in the AR process: two in these illustrations.  Associated with each characteristic direction is a number, its "root" or "eigenvalue."  When the *size* of the number is less than unity, the flow in that characteristic direction is *towards* a central location.  When the size of the root is greater than unity, the flow accelerates *away* from a central location.  Movement along a characteristic direction with a *unit* root--one whose size is $1$--is dominated by the random forces affecting the cone.  It is a "random walk."  The cone can wander away slowly but without accelerating.

(Some of the figures display the values of both roots in their titles.)

Even Pooh--a bear of very little brain--would recognize that the stream will capture his fir cone only when all the flow is toward one eddy or whirlpool; otherwise, on one of those random detours the cone will eventually find itself under the influence of that part of the flow with a root greater than $1$ in magnitude, whence it will wander off downstream and be lost forever.  Consequently, **an AR process can be stationary if and only if all characteristic values are less than unity in size**.

Economists are perhaps the greatest analysts of time series and employers of the AR process technology.  Their series of data typically do not accelerate out of sight.  They are concerned, therefore, only whether there is a characteristic direction whose value may be as large as $1$ in size: a "unit root."  Knowing whether the data are consistent with such a flow can tell the economist much about the potential fate of his pooh stick: that is, about what will happen in the future.  That's why it can be important to test for a unit root.  A fine [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_root#Unit_root_hypothesis) explains some of the implications.

Pooh and his friends found an empirical test of stationarity:

> Now one day Pooh and Piglet and Rabbit and Roo were all playing
> Poohsticks  together.  They had dropped their sticks in when Rabbit
> said "Go!" and then they had hurried across to  the other  side  of
> the bridge, and now they were all leaning over the edge, waiting to
> see whose stick would come out first.  But it was a long time coming,
> because the river was very lazy that day,  and  hardly seemed to mind
> if it didn't ever get there at all.
>
> "I can  see  mine!"  cried  Roo.  "No,  I  can't,  it's something  else.  Can  you see yours, Piglet? I thought I could see
> mine, but I couldn't. There it is! No, it  isn't.  Can  you see yours,
> Pooh?"
>
> "No," said Pooh.
>
> "I  expect  my  stick's  stuck,"  said Roo. "Rabbit, my stick's stuck. Is your stick stuck, Piglet?"
>
> "They always take longer than you think," said Rabbit.

This passage, from 1928, could be construed as the very first "Unit Roo test."

Comment: My apologies for the last line.

Comment: +1 @whuber: I think you've set a new standard for this site. I'll be sorely disappointed at any future intuitive explanations that don't involve diagrams and Winnie the Pooh.

Comment: @whuber A very entertaining explanation of the unit root that does avoid mathematics. +1 for that. But it does look like it took a book chapter to do the explanation.  Also the reader has to take on faith that a root of 1 marks the boundary of statisonaity. To show that I think would necessarily involve some mathematics with the polynomial equation.  The pun at the end "Unit Roo" in place of "Unit Root" was priceless.

Comment: The connection between the size of a root and behavior of the process is easily made with a separate argument that shows why polynomials are red herrings here: the root is a *rate of growth*. This comes down to the fact that multiplying numbers of magnitude greater than $1$ will increase the magnitudes, etc. Your point about the length of the explanation is on the mark. Imagine the context though: a friend or family member asks you this question during a leisurely chat. Would you limit your answer to a few equations, or would you be gently expansive in an effort to help them really understand?

Comment: Another great answer. I often learn things, even when I already had a decent understanding of the topic at hand, from reading your posts.

Comment: @whuber I am not being critical of your explanation at all.  I like it as much as everyone else. But I was trying to defend my point that you can't really explain the unit root without taking a look at the characteristic polynomial which would require at least a little mathematics. The growth of numbers greater than 1 exploding the process is exactly what I show with a manipulation of the equation for the autoregressive process.

Comment: I cannot agree with you that the polynomial is a red herring. the root is related to the autoregressive parameters. You can make the point based on the lag 1 correlation parameter of the AR(1) model but to talk about it in the context of a unit root you have to connect it to the characteristic polynomial.  Your river diagrams do a great job of showing what is going on physically with the process but it does not explain why the eigenvalues are equal to the numbers that you gave.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is merely a mathematical device to collect the eigenvalues into one object, Michael. Although it is thus extraordinarily useful, it can also obscure what is going on. Both geometrically and algebraically, we are selecting a new basis for a vector space and studying the process from that new point of view.  This decomposes the process into a linear combination of one-dimensional processes. The root of each is just a multiplier: that leads to the statement I made. Moreover, these roots usually are found by methods that *avoid* solving the characteristic polynomial!

Answer (score 70):

Imagine two $AR(1)$ processes:

- Process 1: $v_k = 0.5 v_{k-1} + \epsilon_{k-1}$
- Process 2: $v_k = v_{k-1} + \epsilon_{k-1}$
- $\epsilon_i$ is drawn from $N(0,1)$

Process 1 has no unit root.  Process 2 has a unit root.  You can confirm this by calculating characteristic polynomials per Michael's answer.

Imagine we start both processes off at zero, i.e. $v_1 = 0$.  Now imagine what happens when we have a "good run" of positive epsilons, and imagine that both process get to $v_{10} = 5$.

What happens next?  Where do we expect the sequence to go?

We expect that $\epsilon_{i} = 0$.  So we expect that Process 1 case to have $v_{11} = 2.5$, $v_{12} = 1.25$, $v_{13} = 0.625$ etc.

But we expect for Process 2 that $v_{11} = 5$, $v_{12} = 5$, $v_{13} = 5$ etc.

So one intuition is, when a "run of good/bad luck" pushes a process with a unit root around, the sequence "gets stuck in position" by the historical good or bad luck. It will still shift around randomly, but there's nothing "forcing it back". On the other hand, when there's no unit root and the process doesn't blow up, there's a "force" on the process which will make the process drift back to the old position, although the random noise will still knock it around a bit.

The "getting stuck" can include undamped oscillations, a simple example is: $v_k = -v_{k-1} + \epsilon_{k-1}$.  This will bounce back and forth positive to negative, but the oscillation is not predestined to explode out to infinity or damp down to zero.  You can get more forms of "getting stuck" which include more complex kinds of oscillations.

Comment: good answer Patrick.  Dome nice intuitive arguments but not void of mathematics.

Comment: @Patrick Caldon: great answer also, and compliments very well Michael Chernick's. As I said in his answer, I also like these "intuitive mathematical" way of explaining!

Comment: +1: It doesn't mention Winnie the Pooh, but it is quite illustrative none-the-less.

Answer (score 47):

Consider the first-order autoregressive process
$$X_t= aX_{t-1} + e_t$$  where $e_t$ is white noise.  The model can also be expressed with all $X$'s on one side as $$X_t-aX_{t-1} = e_t.$$

Using the backshift operator $BX_t = X_{t-1}$ we can re-express the model compactly as $X_t-aBX_t =e_t$ or, equivalently, $$(1-aB)X_t = e_t.$$  The characteristic polynomial is $1-ax$.  This has a (unique) root at $x=1/a$.  Then for $|a|\lt 1$ we have a stationary $AR(1)$ process and for $|a|\gt 1$ we have an explosive nonstationary $AR(1)$ process.  For $a=1$ we have a random walk which is nonstationary and a *unit* root $x=1/1=1$.  So the unit roots form the boundary between stationarity and nonstationarity.  The $AR(1)$ model (by virtue of its linear characteristic polynomial) is the simplest to illustrate it.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why everything I read about this subject ignores the possibility $a \le -1$ or, more generally, appears insensitive to the possibility that a root of the characteristic polynomial can have unit length without being identically $1$.  Could you perhaps shed some light on this?

Comment: Perhaps this could have focused more on the intuition, but I don't think it merited a downvote.  From my perspective, it's actually a quite clear & succinct statement of the unit root.

Comment: I don't think it does Bill.  If a > 1 in abolute value the root lies outside the unit circle.  So a<-1 is just as nonstationary as a>1.  Inside the unit circle the model is stationary. Outside it is nonstationary.  The unit circle is the boundary. In my answer i should have put absolute value sign around a. Is my explanation not as simple as you can find?  Someone actually downvoted it!

Comment: Thanks Gung. I think all I assumed of the OP was that since he knew about the unit root test he would know about the characteristic polynomial stemming from the polynomial in the backshift operator.

Comment: No problem. He may well, but he does ask how it might be explained to a layperson. By which, I'm assuming that he might mean someone who *doesn't* know about the characteristic polynomial; if you click on the linked question given as an example of what he wants, you'll see the answers are much less mathematical. I suspect that's the reason whoever downvoted, although I disagree w/ that choice & I upvoted (I do think it's good, even if it misses the intuition part). Btw, to get my attention you have to put @ before my username, I just happened to click on this again.

Comment: @gung Do you think that an intuitive explanation void of mathematics is possible? I think the unit root is just a mathematical nicety that describes in mathamatical terms when the coefficients get so large that the process starts to drift off from any central value that would be required for stationarity. People only do the unit root test because the ploynomial defines the boundary of stationarity.

Comment: The only way I could see being intuitive would be to consider the AR(1) process in a mathematical context Xt+k =a$^k$ Xt+nt where nt is a noise term that is a linear combination of the ets. So if a>1 a$^k$ is causing it to continually get larger.

Comment: I don't honestly know. I can tell you that *I* can't provide one, but that I upvoted the question b/c I think it's worth a try & I'd like to know of one if it exists. I suspect the OP & the anonymous downvoter believe it's possible. I can also tell you, FWIW, that I thought your answer was good. There are others on CV who are very good at providing an intuitive understanding of difficult statistical topics & who know a lot more about time series than I do; this really is a great community--we'll have to wait & see what they come up with.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: I really don't know if intuitive answers void of mathematics are possible in all cases, and "intuitive mathematical" answers like yours are awesome too! Trying to avoid math arguments, in my opinion, is a powerful tool not only to have a better understanding of the statistical concept but to understand better the mathematical arguments also! ;)

Comment: @LucasReis Yes Lucas! That is my point too! I raised this because of a discussion I had here with gung about why someone might have downvoted my answer. It seems that the OP and the anonymous downvoter might think that an intuitive answer without mathematics is possible. Since the unit root idea revolves around polynomial equations I see no way to avoid the mathematics. I am waiting to see an example that does and just wanted to point out to everyone that as excellent as Patrick Caldon's answer is, it cannot avoid some of the mathematics. I would give him 2 up votes if I could.

Comment: Michael, note that @Lucas *is* the OP. :-)

Comment: @cardinal I mention Patrick because I am referring to his solution.

Comment: @cardinal Sorry I get it now.  In addressing Lucas I referred to the OP when I should have said "you" since Lucas is the OP.