# Dickey-Fuller augmented tests: how to choose lags?

Tags: stata, unit-root

I’m trying to model a time series (log_consommation) in a ARIMA(p,d,q) using `Stata`.

So I start by determining d by transforming my time series to make it stationary.

My question is, when performing an augmented Dickey Fuller test to test stationarity, I have to choose the number of lags. Is this number of lags related to the p of the ARMA(p,q) model I will estimate later? How can it be determined without using `dfgls`?

I have tried to use several different lags but I’m not sure how to choose:
I add a table of the results I obtain.

```
dfuller log_consommation, lags(0) regress
regress D.log_consommation l1.log_consommation
estat ic

dfuller log_consommation, lags(1) regress
regress D.log_consommation l1.log_consommation l1.(D.log_consommation)
estat ic

dfuller log_consommation, lags(2) regress
regress D.log_consommation l1.log_consommation l1.(D.log_consommation) l2.(D.log_consommation)
estat ic

dfuller log_consommation, lags(3) regress
regress D.log_consommation l1.log_consommation l1.(D.log_consommation) l2.(D.log_consommation) l3.(D.log_consommation)
estat ic

dfuller log_consommation, lags(4) regress
regress D.log_consommation l1.log_consommation l1.(D.log_consommation) l2.(D.log_consommation) l3.(D.log_consommation) l4.(D.log_consommation)
estat ic
```

I obtain :

```
Augmented Dickey-Fuller test regressions and test statistic
--
                      (1)             (2)             (3)             (4)             (5)             (6)   
                   No lag           1 lag          2 lags          3 lags          4 lags          5 lags   
--
L.log_cons~n      -0.0137***      -0.0105***     -0.00741***     -0.00678**      -0.00662**      -0.00574*  
                  (-8.06)         (-5.12)         (-3.40)         (-2.96)         (-2.76)         (-2.31)   

LD.log_con~n                        0.173*          0.131           0.118           0.113           0.108   
                                   (2.00)          (1.50)          (1.28)          (1.21)          (1.16)   

L2D.log_co~n                                        0.283**         0.249**         0.245*          0.228*  
                                                   (3.34)          (2.82)          (2.62)          (2.43)   

L3D.log_co~n                                                       0.0608          0.0527          0.0217   
                                                                 (0.68)          (0.57)          (0.22)   

L4D.log_co~n                                                                       0.0195        -0.00939   
                                                                                   (0.22)         (-0.10)   

L5D.log_co~n                                                                                        0.119   
                                                                                                   (1.32)   

_cons               0.176***        0.135***       0.0952***       0.0874**        0.0855**        0.0743*  
                   (8.57)          (5.34)          (3.52)          (3.07)          (2.85)          (2.39)   


aic                -888.5          -889.0          -890.1          -881.7          -871.4          -863.4   
bic                -882.8          -880.6          -878.9          -867.7          -854.7          -844.0   
t_ADF              -8.062          -5.118          -3.399          -2.965          -2.759          -2.310   


t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Comment: Point (1) might be relevant: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55859/7071

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ac` and `pac` in Stata to assess the possible lags. However, if you are using the ARMA model, it is normal to estimate `arma` for the candidate models with p=0, q=1 and so on to p=3 and q=3. Then obtain the `aic` and `bic`. The model with the lowest aic or bic is chosen. The lags chosen by these criteria may differ, but you have to make sure that the residuals of these models are white noise at their chosen lags.