# Correcting for random walk

Tags: unit-root

Does taking the first difference of a series with a unit root ALWAYS give us a stationary series? I tried taking the first difference, but Dickey Fuller test tells me the new series still has a unit root... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, it definitely does not always give back a stationary series. For example if your true underlying model is given by an AR(2) : $Y_t = c + \theta_1 Y_{t-1} + \theta_2Y_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$, there is no reason whatsoever why $dY_t$ should *certainly* be stationary. On the contrary most probably it won't be stationary and you would need to take the $d^2Y_t$ to expect something half sensible.

Check the following excellent link on [Intuitive explanation of unit root](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29121/intuitive-explanation-of-unit-root/29129#29129) so you built up some familiarity what the unit-root that the Dickey Fuller test tries to detect actually entails.