# Roots in the characteristic polynomial (ARIMA)

Tags: time-series, arima, polynomial

Why do you have to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial to say whether an ARIMA process is invertible or causal? I do not understand what underpins this method.

Comment: Intuitive accounts are given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29121.