# Why does an AR(p) process require the largest eigenroot to be <1/ characteristic roots lie outsied the unit circle to be stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive

For reference, this is the paragraph in Wikipedia I'm struggling with.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model
[image]

I do understand the simpler proof for under which conditions an AR(1) process is stationary, however I do not understand 
a.) how to make the connection between the condition for AR(1) to be stationary ([image]) and the generalized condition for the root |z| > 1.

b.) How to show that |z|>1 must hold for AR(p) to be stationary and the "intuition" behind the second condition (if there is any)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Some intuition is provided at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29121/intuitive-explanation-of-unit-root/29129#29129.

Comment: Thank you. The link is great for some basic intuition!