# what means to be outside unit circle?

Tags: time-series, definition, unit-root, geometry

I am trying to study time series without a great math background and I came across the next problem:

When checking for stationarity I check the roots, and if they are not on the unit circle, then it confirms the ts is stationary.

My question might be pretty basic: when I get the roots, I am getting scalars, whereas in my mind to be inside/outside unit circle I need coordinates... How do I know if a scalar is inside/outside the unit circle?

And my last question is, I always read "roots are not on the unit circle".

"on" means "inside", right? and if so... Is it the same as saying "roots are outside the unit circle"?

Comment: You are getting *real* scalars, then, which by definition have $0$ for their second coordinates.  Thus, $x$ lies inside the unit circle if and only if $(x,0)$ does, which means $|x|\lt 1.$  "On" literally means on the *circle,* not its interior (which is a *disk*).  Thus, $x$ is on the unit circle if and only if $x=\pm 1.$  For intuition, see the examples at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29129/919.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The roots in this case are roots of a polynomial, and they can be (and often are) complex numbers. That means they have coordinates, in this case called the *real part* and the *imaginary part*. As an example, the polynomial $z^2+1$ has roots, that are solutions of the equation $z^2+1=0$, equal to $z_{1,2}= \pm \sqrt{-1}=\pm i$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is the *imaginary unit*.

In this example, the real and imaginary parts are 
$$\begin{alignat}{4}
   \Re i &=&0  &,& \quad   \Im i &=& 1 \quad \text{and}\\
   \Re{-i}&=&0 &,& \quad \Im{-i} &=&-1 \end{alignat}
$$ and with pairs (or coordinate) representation $i=(0,1), -i=(0,-1)$ and now you can show these two roots are *on the unit circle*.