# Is x(t) = ax(t-1) + e stationary or not?

Tags: stationarity

Is $x(t) = ax(t-1) + e$ a stationary process or not? E.g. with $a=0.8$, I would imagine it is not, but if I graph it with random normal error terms it looks stationary.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25481/7071) as well for a graphical answer.

Comment: See the last part of [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Definition) of the relevant Wikipedia article.